# Bootstrap Switching to Sass Javascript Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have been following along with Ryan's Railscast [328](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics) and [329](http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap).

Things worked great until I switch to bootstrap-sass in 329.  Now I'm getting this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'
```

That is coming from `bootstrap.js`.  `bootstrap.js` is getting loaded after `jquery.js` (which is version 1.7.1.

My `application.js` file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Is there some other file I need to require?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't have a file called `bootstrap` in your javascript folders.  Sprockets finds that file instead of the files in the gem.

Comment: I renamed it to bootstrap-custom.js still am getting the error 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: Specifically, bootstrap.js.coffee probably should be called bootstrapify.js.coffee or something similar.